# How to shorten awk command and add leading zeros to the record count

Tags: linux, awk

I am adding header and trailer records to a file with `awk` commands. How can I shorten/consolidate the `awk` command, is it possible not to use temp files, and do all the manipulations with original file so I can shorten `awk` command that way as well. Also, I need to have the trailer record count 10 bytes long with leading zeros. Here is the `awk` command I am using:

```
awk -v today="$(date +%Y%m%d)" \
  -v last_day="$(date +"%Y%m%d" \
  -d "$(date +%Y-%m-01) +1 month -1 day")" \
  'BEGIN { print "ABCDEFG MC " today " FB XXX1 " today, last_day } 1' \
  original_file.txt > original_file H.txt

awk '{print} END{print "TRL" NR - 1}' \
  original_fileH.txt > original_fileT.txt

rm original_file.txt
rm original_fileH.txt
mv original_fileT.txt original_file.txt
```

Here is file sample:

`Record line 1 Record line 2`

Here file result after `awk` execution:

`ABCDEFG MC 20201007 FB XXX1 20201007 20201031 Record line 1 Record line 2 TRL3`

Comment: Perhaps you can use `sed` to add the header to the file and then use `echo`/`>>` to add the trailing lines? I don't think you need `awk` at all, because you're not manipulating the file. If you just need to count the lines, you might as well use `wc`.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't use your date functions for the sake of clarity and also as the question here is more of an `awk` thing.

Basically for the file `awk1` with contents:

```
Record line 1 Record line 2
```

We can use the following one-liner

```
cat awk1 | awk -v val1="foo" -v val2="bar" '{ print "START " val1 " MIDDLE " val2 " " $0 " END " NF }'
START foo MIDDLE bar Record line 1 Record line 2 END 6
```

Basically, you don't need the `BEGIN` or `END` unless you're doing things like headers or summaries. Tranposing in variables in the right positions here should give you what you want.

Comment: Note: `cat awk1` is a *UUOc* (*Unnecessary Use Of* `cat`). `awk` can read directly from the file and you avoid the additional processes for `cat` and the pipe tying the streams together.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to add a header and a tail, you could just do the following:

```
awk -v today="$(date +%Y%m%d)"                                              \
    -v last_day="$(date -d "$(date +%Y-%m-01) +1 month -1 day")" "+%Y%m%d"  \
    'BEGIN { print "ABCDEFG MC",today,"FB XXX1",today, last_day }
     1; END {print "TRL", NR}' file1 > file2
mv file2 file1
```

If you have GNU awk, you can clean it up a bit more:

```
awk -i inplace                                                                   \
    'BEGIN{ today=strftime("%Y%m%d"); Y=substr(today,1,4); m=substr(today,5,2)
            last_day=strftime(mktime(Y" "m+1" -1 0 0 0"))
            print "ABCDEFG MC",today,"FB XXX1",today, last_day }
     1;END{print "TRL", NR}' file1
```